# Single sign-on with MSAL.js?

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

It it possible to get single sign-on for my application when already authenticated to AzureAD?

Prossible flow:

1. Signed in as an AzureAD user
2. Go to my app
3. Redirected to
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/authorize?client_id=clientid (ish) -> which returns a token and
   redirects back to my application

Next time i use my application if i got a valid cookie i'm not redirected to microsoftonline.com and can start using my app directly.

In short, I would like to get to the callback without displaying the popup for the end user:

```
var userAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication("your_client_id", null, function (errorDes, token, error, tokenType) {
      // this callback is called after loginRedirect OR acquireTokenRedirect (not used for loginPopup/aquireTokenPopup)
})
userAgentApplication.loginPopup(["user.read"]).then( function(token) {
    var user = userAgentApplication.getUser();
    if (user) {
       // signin successful
    } else {
       // signin failure
    }
}, function (error) {
    // handle error
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If specify the tenant and only one user is signed into azure ad before , you could directly sign into your app if `prompt=none`(by default) . You can't achieve that with MSAL.JS , refer to source code of MSAL.JS ：

```
 var urlNavigate = authenticationRequest.createNavigateUrl(scopes) + "&prompt=select_account" + "&response_mode=fragment";
```

It will set `prompt=select_account` will redirect user to select account page . If you are using Azure AD accounts and just want to login a specific tenant , you could try ADAL.JS (will not force prompt=select_account). If that is a multi-tenant app(use `common` instead of tenant id ) , you can't avoid user selecting page with azure ad v2.0 endpoint .

Notice :If the user is signed into azure ad with multiple accounts , you can't avoid user selecting page , that is by design , user should has the opportunity to choose which account he or she wants to use for signing into the application .

Comment: Thanks, got it working with ADAL.js but was hoping to migrate to MSAL.

Comment: If you are using ADFS and the user is signed into azure ad with multiple accounts,  it use  the account which is used in ADFS login automatically independent from which account was selected on select_account popup.

Answer (score 2):

Use [acquireTokenSilent](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/docs/classes/_useragentapplication_.msal.useragentapplication.html#acquiretokensilent) instead of loginPopup, and pass your client ID as the scope. If the promise is rejected, then you need to call one of the other functions to log in.